# Why catkin_make_isolated on Rasberry Pi?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am puzzled by the fact that various instructions for putting ROS on a Raspi use catkin_make_isolated and related scripts, and end up creating build_isolated and devel_isolated. Is that required? Why would I not want to do a regular catkin_make?

(and perhaps related, why did it call the directory the non-standard ros_catkin_ws?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357925/why-catkin_make_isolated-on-rasberry-pi?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Why would I not want to do a regular catkin_make?

because most RPi installations are built-from-sources, which will include non-Catkin packages.

Plain `catkin_make` cannot build non-Catkin packages.

`catkin_make_isolated` can.

> and perhaps related, why did it call the directory the non-standard ros_catkin_ws?

Because there is no requirement on what the name of the workspace is?

It's also not important: that workspace is really "only" a workspace used while building the initial, base ROS install from sources. Most instructions will end with a `catkin_make_isolated` command which `install`s the resulting binaries into `/opt/ros/..` (or a similar read-only location).

After that, the temporary `ros_catkin_ws` can be deleted and a regular workspace can be created and used (which will contain just the packages the user is working *on*, rather than *with*).

Unless a user wishes to track upstream and benefit from re-using some of the binary objects in the `build_isolated` directory of course. Then it should not be deleted. But perhaps something like `ccache` would be better to use in that case.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-07-25**:
Important things I did not know! Especially that I can delete the make_isolated ws. It all makes sense.